# Heating of mixture of gases with one gas barely above its boiling point

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, gas

What happens when mixture of two gases is heated in a closed container?

If one gas expands faster than the other and increases pressure of the container enough so that the boiling point of the other gas is decreased below the gas temperature, will second gas start turning into liquid?

This phase change must also give out heat, causing the overall temperature and pressure to further increase.

Is this valid? or mixture of two gases work lot different than two of them separately?

Comment: Can you give a specific example so we have something concrete to work with?

Comment: Your problem is that you talk about a mixture of gases while pretending the gases are somehow separate nonetheless. When you heat up the **mixture** it behaves like one and expands like one. Increasing its temperature increases its pressure but it still behaves like a mixture, not two containers, each containing one gas. Each gas has a *partial* pressure, proportional to its mol fraction in the mixture and the total pressure of the mixture.

Comment: I also can't see a single example of a gas (pure) that would condense on heating because that increases its pressure. Look at p,V,T diagrams, e.g.: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pVT+diagram&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7DSGP_enGB473&gfe_rd=cr&ei=RbpJV6byDcrU8gesoKuQCQ&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: With a constant volume, the ratio of partial pressure between the two gases is their mole number ratio. So if you raise partial pressure of one gas by 2 times, you will raise the partial pressure of the other gas by 2 times as well. No gas goes faster. And if you heat the container, you raise temperature of both gases. The vapor pressures increase as well. So you may not be able to liquefy any gas at all.

Comment: this might not happen because as some molecules condense, it will take significant moles from the gas phase, thus decreasing the pressure.

Comment: Thanks, so in theory this could work with some magical super gas mixture, there are several obstacles.

Comment: As pointed out by @Gert no gas has properties that will condense it at high temperature. But will it work if we have a particular gas already at a high pressure? so reducing the problem to a limiting it to only one gas. Say steam (water vapor) at 1 atm, in a closed container at 100 centigrade. Now will this turn partially to water if we keep heating it? I guess for water the answer is no since the pvt charts show clearly that pressure will never outrun the temp. Is there some specific physics/chemistry behind it that makes it impossible to happen for any gas?

Comment: *Is there some specific physics/chemistry behind it that makes it impossible to happen for any gas? * Condensation is an exothermic process, heat is released when condensation takes place. You can see how that isn't compatible with *adding* heat to the system.

Comment: @Gert doesn't the pressure cooker work on the same principle? Initially water boils  but as pressure increases some of it condenses (or further boiling is prevented?).

Comment: @bainonline: Not really, no. What a pressure shows is that boiling point goes up with pressure. But you start from liquid, it starts boiling, then ends up boiling at > 100 C. Had the pressure cooker been filled with water vapour you'd have ended up with steam at > 100 C but no condensate at all.